# java script function run after 2 mouseevent condition

Tags: javascript

I have 3 boxes: kotak1, kotak2, and kotak3.

`#kotak1` has the test `"COBA AKU"`

CSS:

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #mainCont {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1024px;
        height: 768px;
        background-color: #F00;
    }
    #kotak1{
        width: 1024px;
        height: 768px;
        background-color: #0F9;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #kotak2{
        width: 240px;
        height: 768px;
        background-color: #666;
        float: left;
    }
    #kotak3{
        width: 240px;
        height: 768px;
        background-color: #03F;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainCont">
        <div id="kotak2"></div>
        <div id="kotak3" onmouseout="keluarkotak()"></div>
        <div id="kotak1">
            COBA AKU
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to change the text in `#kotak1` to `"SELESAI TIDUR"` when the you mouse out from `#kotak3` and enter `#kotak2`.

Comment: Show what you've tried, and we'll help you fix it. If it's not working, make sure you've checked the Javascript console for errors.

Comment: I agree.  There needs to be some of the JavaScript function here in order to see where your error is.  Even if it isn't working, it is helpful to post your attempt so that you can learn where you are going wrong in your code, or possibly your approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PZfwT/1

Here's the supporting code, just manage whether you've left three and then when your mouse enters 2 you can change the text of 1. I'd recommend doing this with jQuery, it's easier to manage overall if done that way.

```
(function() {
    var mousedOutThree = false;

    window.App = {
        kotak2In: function() {
            if (mousedOutThree) {
                mousedOutThree = false;
                document.getElementById("kotak1").innerHTML = "SELESAI TIDUR";   
            }
        },

        kotak3Out: function() {
            mousedOutThree = true;
        }
    };
})();
```